# Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm - not recognising pip installed packages

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

OK, Going nuts here.
I have Pycharm set up - I have an interpreter configured from a virtual env with hdbscan installed using pip

[image: Image from pycharm settings]

This is configured as the project default for the jupyter server

[image: Jupyter server settings]

whenever I fire up my jupyter server by running a cell in my workbook in Pycharm or in an external browser hdbscan won't import and a quick sanity check gives this insanity:

[image: Output from cell checking for hdbscan and importing it]

I have checked hdbscan and jupyter are not installed in the global python environment - this makes no sense to me. I have the same problem with several other packages added to the environment (sklearn, plotly). Not sure how pip show can report a package being present that then can't be imported in the same environment. Any suggestions ?